# How to pass whole object in data of datatable column property

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm using a Datatables 1.10.21 and using ajax, column property to generate the datatables.
All is working fine.

```
ajax: {
            url: dataUrl,          //using dataUrl veriable
            dataSrc: 'data'
        },
 columns: [
                { data: 'fundRuleName' },
                { data: 'fundRuleTypeName' },
                { data: 'fundCycleName' },
                { data: 'fundCalculationTypeName' },
                { data: 'flatCalculationFilterName' },
                { data: 'amount' },
                { data: 'applicableDate', render: function (data) { return dd_mm_yyyy(data) } },
                { data: 'endDate', render: function (data) { return data ? dd_mm_yyyy(data) : '' } },
                {
                    data: '[0]',
                    render: function (data) {
                        return generateButton(data);
                    },
                }
            ]
```

I'm passing the JSON data in "data" variable. everything is working fine except last column. I'm able to pass any property of an object in the "generateButton(data)" function but I want to pass the whole object.
is there any way to do that?

I tried below methods but didn't work.

1. {data: '[0]', render: function (data) {return generateButton(data);}}
2. {data: '[]', render: function (data) {return generateButton(data);}}
3. {data: 'data[]', render: function (data) {return generateButton(data);}}
4. {data: '[data]', render: function (data) {return generateButton(data);}}
5. {data: 'data', render: function (data) {return generateButton(data);}}
6. {data: 'data{}', render: function (data) {return generateButton(data);}}
7. {data: '{data}', render: function (data) {return generateButton(data);}}

If you found something then please let me know.

Comment: Could you show us your `generateButton()`code, please?

Comment: function generateButton(data) {
        return '<a onclick="openFundRuleForm(' + data + ')"  rule" data-toggle="tooltip" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>'
    }

Comment: @Sagnalrac  {data: null,render: function (data) {return generateButton(data);},} works!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass **null**.

Look at my example:

```js
var dataUrl = "https://my-json-server.typicode.com/SagnalracSO/repoJD/employees?_limit=3";

var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  ajax: {
    url: dataUrl,          //using dataUrl veriable
    dataSrc: ''
  },
  columns: [
    { data: 'firstName' },
    { data: 'lastName' },
    { data: 'position' },
    { data: 'office' },
    { data: 'age' },
    { data: 'startDate' },
    { data: 'salary' },
    { data: 'extn' },
    { data: 'email' },
    {
      data: null,
      render: function (data, row, full) {
        return generateButton(data);
      },
    }
  ]
});

function generateButton(data) { 
    
    var dataItem = JSON.stringify(data);
    
    return "<a onclick='openFundRuleForm(" + dataItem + ")' rule data-toggle='tooltip' class='btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary'><i class='fas fa-edit'></i></a>";
}

function openFundRuleForm(data) {
   console.log(data);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start Date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
      <th>Ext #</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```